# Fields can see in workbench but when i query it says no such column on entity

Tags: apex, soql, standard-objects

I can see the Mediumphotourl field for the user object in the workbench but when i try to query it i am getting an error No Such column 'MediumPhotoUrl' on entity 'USER'

Comment: What is the API version of class?

Comment: Check Field Level Security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MediumPhotoUrl` field on User was introduced in API v37.0. If your Apex class has api version lower than that, you won't be able to query that field.

**Solution**: Increase the API version of Apex class to v37.0 or above to be able to access that field.